# Updating one table with data from other tables. (With addition)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two simple tables:

```
Table: POP_UP (ACC_NR, AMOUNT);
Table: ACCOUNT (ACC_NR, SUM, CUST_ID);
```

And I am trying to figure out how to update SUM in Table ACCOUNT, when I am entering information in to the table POP_UP. Should I go with trigers or is there are another way to do so?

Comment: Triggers would be the appropriate solution -- unless you decide to forego pre-computing the value and just use a view instead.

Comment: `sum` is the sum of `amount` in `pop_up` for an `acc_nr`?

Comment: From my point of view, you shouldn't be doing it at all. If you need to know that information, any time you want run `select sum(amount) from pop_pu where acc_nr = ...`

Comment: Table POP_UP is used to keep records of amounts added to  ACCOUNT. So the SUM in the ACCOUNT should be the SUM of all AMOUNTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do it.

1. Using `View`, which is recommended as there is no need to store the same data to different tables -- integrity will be compromised
2. Using `Trigger`, which will generate data in the `ACCOUNT` table using data of `POP_UP` table

Here is the code for View:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ACCOUNT_SUM_VW AS
    SELECT
        ACC_NR,
        SUM(P.AMOUNT) AS SUM_,
        A.CUST_ID
    FROM
        ACCOUNT A
        LEFT JOIN POP_UP P USING ( ACC_NR )
    GROUP BY
        ACC_NR,
        A.CUST_ID;
```

Code for Trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER POP_UP_AIUD_TRG AFTER
    INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON POP_UP
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
LV_AMOUNT ACCOUNT.SUM_%TYPE;
BEGIN
    IF INSERTING THEN
        LV_AMOUNT := :NEW.AMOUNT;
    ELSIF UPDATING THEN
        LV_AMOUNT := :NEW.AMOUNT - :OLD.AMOUNT;
    ELSIF DELETING THEN
        LV_AMOUNT := 0 - :OLD.AMOUNT;
    END IF;
        UPDATE ACCOUNT A
        SET
            A.SUM_ =  COALESCE(A.SUM_,0) + COALESCE(LV_AMOUNT,0)
        WHERE
            A.ACC_NR = COALESCE(:NEW.ACC_NR,:NEW.ACC_NR);
END;
/
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=aca84b6f93a319126d2f2c8b04d6fa21)

Cheers!!